# How to upload a safe image with PHP?

Tags: php, image, security

I know there is a big amount of questions about this but I cannot get one that involves all I want to be aware of.

What I want to do is to allow the users of my webpage to upload images with a form. And I want to do this process secure, or at least as much secure I can.

I do not know too much about security in terms of deep inside of it, but I am aware of about all the consequences that a insecure webpage can produce. And I cannot be quiet thinking that my webpage is insecure or that anyone is not going to enter into my webpage because it does not have enough visits(I am realist).

At this point, I know that all the checks about security have to be done on server side instead of client side (or in both).

I know that a file can be fooled as an image and run malicious code so I searched about methods to avoid this. This is what I could find to check before store the image on the server:

**From `$_FILES`**:

- `$_FILES['file']['name']`: To check that the file that I have uploaded have a name. To know that the file exists.
- `$_FILES['file']['error']`: To check if the image have an error.
- `$_FILES['file']['size']`: To check that the size of the image is bigger than 0.
- `$_FILES['file']['type']`: To check that the type of the file is an image but it is not recommended because `PHP` does not check it.

**General functions:**

- Check [`magic numbers`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files) to verify the image type.
- [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/exif_imagetype): To check the type of an image.
- [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize): To check if it returns a 0 which means that the file is not an image.
- [`imagecreatefromstring()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php): To create a new image giving a string. If it cannot be created, then is not an image.
- [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php): To create a `PNG` image to remove all meta-data (using [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) and [`imagecopy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)).

But the problem I have is that I do not know if I should use all of these methods or just avoid or add some of them (because some of them seems redundant).

And my questions are:

- Should I use all of them?
- Have I to add another one method to be more secure?
- Could be the order in which I filter the file critic? I mean, is it better to use one filter before another and viceversa? If so, what should be the order and why?

**Note:** I am not searching about personal opinion. I tried to gather all info I could, but I cannot be sure if it is ok or not talking about security terms. If you can put examples of something that it is forgotten it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am using the Fileinfo extension to get the MIME type and check it against a whitelist. If it is ok, I recreate the image to remove any unnecessary metadata (I use Imagick, but it also works with GD (until a specific limit).

Comment: Glad I could share some tips. I have a modular Cleaner / Sanitizer / Validator class system / routine that I use to secure user input, but I never got around to implementing my FileSanitizer and FileValidator classes. But, your question and my answer cover the basics of what I intend to do.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for your comment! I am interested about what you have put in your comment because I did not heard about it before. What do you mean with `Fileinfo` extension and MIME? I searched about MIME and what I understood is that it was created for email transmissions but nowadays it is used in all web transmissions and sets a header with the type of file that is being transfered, right? A whitelist could be a simple array in which you have stored the different types allowed and check it vs the MIME type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You don't need to use *all* of those methods, and which ones you use are going to be based on personal opinion. Meaning to say, there is more than one perfectly secure way to do it so don't be suprised if you get multiple different answers.
2. See examples below for additional checks you might have left out
3. Yes, the order definitely matters.

Depending on your application, the logic for any secure upload should flow something like this:

**Is the user logged in? (optional)**

```
// make sure user is logged in
if (!$user->loggedIn()) {
    // redirect
}
```

**Does the user have permission? (optional)**

```
// make sure user has permission
if (!$user->isAllowed()) {
    // redirect
}
```

**Was the form submitted?**

```
// make sure form was submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

**Is the form input valid?**

```
// validate CSRF token
// ...

// make sure there were no form errors
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

// make sure the file size is good
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] <= MAX_FILE_UPLOAD) {

// make sure we have a valid image type
$type = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if ($type !== false) {

// make sure we check the type against a whitelist
if (in_array(ltrim(image_type_to_extension($type), '.'), array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'))) {
```

**Even after validating, never trust user input**

```
// give the file a unique name
$hash = hash_file('sha1', $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$ext = image_type_to_extension($type);
$fname = $hash . $ext;
```

**Save the file (or optionally recreate it with a library to strip out meta-data) but NEVER in a publicly accessible directory**

```
$upload_path = '/path/to/private/folder';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "$upload_path/$fname");
```

The steps above are perfectly secure and more than reasonable, of course there is always a risk that some other part of your application or server might be vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The only one thing that I do not understand why you do it is to hash the file. I used hash to store passwords on the database, but never on files. And I am glad that someone thinks like me as the user validation first :)

Comment: @Error404 the hash is just one example of giving the file a unique name. If you end up with 2 identical hashes, then it's safe to assume the image is a duplicate.

Comment: So I guess that after creating this hash I have to compare with the files that are inside the folder, right?

Comment: @Error404 yes, unless you want to overwrite it

Comment: And one more question: how to know what is the order that I have to follow? I guess that in your case you put your steps in order but, in general terms, what should be first and what later? Thanks again!

Comment: And I do not understand why you get the extension of the extension itself when you do `$ext = image_type_to_extension($type);`. Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: @Error404 because `$type` is an integer returned by `exif_imagetype`, not the actual extension. The `image_type_to_extension` function finds the actual extension.

Comment: And by order, you go with what makes sense logically. Checking the file size before making sure the form was submitted or has no errors, for example, would be backwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you get enough responses, you might have a good answer!  :-)

### Operating System

Make sure you have a dedicated volume for the files. Or, at minimum, have quota set on the directory. Make sure you have enough inodes and such, if on Linux/Unix. A bunch of small files can be just as deadly as a few gigantic files. Have a dedicated uploads directory. Set where the temp files should go in your php.ini. Make sure your file permission are safe (chmod), too. Use Linux ACLs, if necessary, to fine tune permissions. Test, test, test.

### PHP

Incorporate the knowledge found here into your uploaded file handling algorithm [PHP Manual: POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Take the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` bit with a grain of salt.

1. Make sure you know what your max up load file size is. Set it accordingly. There may be other file related settings. Be sure to lock those in before getting around to the `$_FILES` superglobal.
2. Do not work with the uploaded files directly, and do not use the name attribute at all to give the file a real file name. Use, `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()` appropriately.
3. Use `tmp_name` appropriately.
4. Be wary of null bytes on file names! Yes, you still need to **filter** and **validate** any string that represents user input (especially if you intend on using it any way).
5. First things first, check for the presence of a file.
6. Second, check the size in bytes.

If anything in #5 or #6 fail, the validation process should end. For a robust routine, incorporate the idea that at sometime you may want to upload *multiple files* at one time ([PHP Manual: Uploading Multiple Files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)). In that case, the $_FILES superglobal may not look like you would expect. See the link above for more details.

### GD

You've got the general idea about using these functions to open the submitted file (without using the user submitted name, that is). Just come up with a logical series of progressive steps. I don't have those steps, but if meta-data can be a problem, that would seem high on the list of GD stuff to try early (after basic file presence and size stuff). I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! I have some questions: **1.** When you say _Set where the temp files should go in your php.ini._ do you mean to change the default tmp_file, right? **2.** When you say _Use, is_uploaded_file() and move_uploaded_file() appropriately._, what do you mean with _use appropiately_? What should I do? **3.** What do you mean with GD? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *1*. Yes, search the php.ini and you will find the setting for where uploaded files should go. *2*. You have to read the manual. That is the best advice I can give. Just don't use the user supplied file name. Alternatively, filter and validate it thoroughly. *3*. The GD sequence is not set in stone. You'll have to research it. Again, I don't have those steps. Niel's answer is a GD sequence, but I cannot testify to its completeness.

Comment: Too bad my Stack Overflow account is in the penalty box. I have not been able to ask question since I had about 400 points! But, I'm glad to help where I can. The tell me if I get enough points, that I can get out of the penalty box.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply! When I refer to what do you mean on GD, I wanted to ask what does the letters G and D mean to make a search on the Internet. And about the penalty box, I never had heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following with an apparent image upload:

**1) Use is_uploaded_file() to ensure you've not been fooled into working on something else entirely**

```
if(!is_uploaded_file($yourfile))
     return false;
```

**2) Check the mimetype with exif_imagetype() and block anything you don't want**

```
   $allowed_images = array(IMAGETYPE_BMP, IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);

    $uType = exif_imagetype($yourfile);
    if(!in_array($uType, $allowed_images))
    {
        unlink($yourfile);
        return false;
    }
```

**3) Use Imagick to remake the image and remove all comments and metadata:**

```
    $image = new Imagick($yourfile);
    $image->resizeImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);
    $image->stripImage();         // remove all comments and similar metadata
```

**4) Write the replacement image to the filesystem and erase the original file:**

```
$image->writeImage("/path/to/new/image");
unlink($yourfile);
```

**5) Upload this image to S3.**

```
 // your S3 code here
```

**6) Make a note of the image's S3 URL in the database or wherever.**

```
 // your database code here
```

**7) Erase the replacement image.**

```
 unlink("/path/to/new/image");
```

Comment: I need to learn the "file image" algorithm part for my Cleaner / Filter / Validator classes. I've seem similar steps else where. I'll definitely keep your answer in mind. --Anthony

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is great! I have some questions: **1.** I have searched about MIME type and what I understood is that is a header in all web transactions that has the type of the file sending, right? **2.** What do you mean what you put S3? **3.** You did not use most of the methods that I put on my question. Should I use them? Should I avoid them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: **1** I check the mime type to reduce the chances of feeding garbage into ImageMagick. I suppose it is possible to upload something malicious that carries the right mimetype header, but remaking the image without metadata and comments should guard against that.

**2** I should have explained this better. I aim to store all static assets (like images) on a platform that is not my web server. I like to use the AWS S3 service. This has two benefits: first my web server only has to worry about dynamic files, and second if the upload is malicious it is moved to a platform that cannot execute it.

Comment: **3** I think that by recreating the image with Imagick, the extra checks you've suggested become redundant, but it can't do any harm (performance aside) to test with those too. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you again! Your info is really helpful but it would be great if you can add the info about S3 on your answer. I think it would be helpful to highlight that info there. Thank you :)